# Low performance with MPI communication within a single node

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I have a program that is using the openMPI implementation of MPI for data-exchange between processes. Right now I am using this program on only one node, where the data has to be shared from one process to all the others. The total amount of data that the master process is sending is 130 Gb, which is split and sent to 6-8 client processes, but this data-transfer takes an awful amount of time (1 hour).
Knowing that the code is running on the very same node, I would expect that the data-transfer could use some speed-up, through the settings that I could describe when I launch the mpirun program - Do you know which settings could help me to get a faster data-transfer in this scenario? Right now I am using only "--mca btl vader,self" as optional components.

The actual code use MPI_Send() functions that share an amount of data that is near to the maximum amount of data that is possible to transfer with this call. After the data has been transferred to a client-process after multiple MPI_Send() calls, the master process send data to the other pending client-processes.

Comment: 130 Gb is a lot of data - how much memory does your computer have? One explanation is that you could be running out of memory and the huge time is due to paging to/from disk. What happens if you run with smaller data sets, e.g. 1 Gb?

Comment: Thanks David, there is no paging disk file and the node has 1tb of ram. With smaller datasets, the amount of time scales almost linearly